# Filter based index array in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I need to find a way to filter the variables of an array, following the index of each variable.
So far I only have the following example.

```
DATA[nidforusr1]='jamaica'
DATA[nidforusr2]='brasil'
DATA[nidforusr3]='janaina'
DATA[nidforusr4]='cebola'
DATA[nidforusr5]='batata' 
DATA[nidforbkp1]='ketchup'
DATA[pwforusr1]='sorvete'
DATA[pwforusr2]='google'
DATA[pwforusr3]='pesado'
DATA[pwforusr4]='maluco'
DATA[pwforusr5]='programador'
DATA[pwforbkp1]='macaco'
DATA[ipforusr1]='batata'
DATA[ipforusr2]='senha'
DATA[ipforusr3]='microfone'
DATA[ipforusr4]='passarinho'
DATA[ipforusr5]='abobora'
DATA[ipforbkp1]='caixa'

for ((i=0;i<=${#DATA[@]};i++))
do
    echo "${DATA[@]:nidforusr1:nidforusr*}"
done

---------------- OR ------------------

for i in ${!DATA[@]}
do
  if [[ "$i" == "nidforusr*" ]]
  then
    echo "${DATA[i]}"
  fi
done
```

I want to filter the contents of array, but only the contents of array variable that start with index nidforusr

Here's the challenge.

Comment: Please translate your question to English. Why do you put *jamaica* etc. in apostrophs? Is `nidforusr1` etc. a variable?

Comment: Why do you have the variables in an array in the first place? What do you want to filter? `if [ "$i" == "nidforusr*" ]` -> does `if [ "$i" == "nidforusr"* ]` answer your question? If you put `*` it's `*` not glob.

Comment: nidforusr1 is a index of DATA array variable.

Comment: [ "$i" == "nidforusr"* ] didn't works

Comment: @YohrannesSantosBigoli `[ ]` tests don't support wildcard matching; `[[ ]]` conditional expressions do. See [BashFAQ #31: "What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) and the Unix&Linux question ["What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Comment: Ok, but still didn't work with [[ ]]

Comment: I want to filter the contents of arrays, but only the contents of arrays that start with index nidforusr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fix the position of `*` and change `[i]` to `[$i]`, it should work.

```bash
declare -A DATA

DATA[nidforusr1]='jamaica'
DATA[nidforusr2]='brasil'
DATA[nidforusr3]='janaina'
DATA[nidforusr4]='cebola'
DATA[nidforusr5]='batata' 
DATA[nidforbkp1]='ketchup'
DATA[pwforusr1]='sorvete'
DATA[pwforusr2]='google'
DATA[pwforusr3]='pesado'
DATA[pwforusr4]='maluco'
DATA[pwforusr5]='programador'
DATA[pwforbkp1]='macaco'
DATA[ipforusr1]='batata'
DATA[ipforusr2]='senha'
DATA[ipforusr3]='microfone'
DATA[ipforusr4]='passarinho'
DATA[ipforusr5]='abobora'
DATA[ipforbkp1]='caixa'

for i in ${!DATA[@]}
do
  if [[ "$i" == "nidforusr"* ]]
  then
    echo "${DATA[$i]}"
  fi
done
```